# How to test in robolectric whether i opened a fragment on button click?

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit4, robolectric

I have a few buttons, on clicking on them i open different dialog fragments. I want to know how to test whether does dialog open ? or if it opens is it of correct type?

Please Help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Well I figure it out by myself. From this very good tutorial by Colin Miller (Sr software engineer @ LinkedIn) i will be able to solve this.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UEklodQTJZY

This question might not be useful but this tutorial is definitely useful.

---

Solution of this problem is:

```
button.performClick()

XDialogFragment dialog = (XDialogFragment) activity
                .getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(XDialogFragment.TAG);

Assert.assertNotNull(dialog);
```

Comment: Couldn't the fragment be found by tag being in the fragmentmanager's backstack and not be visible?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem doing my unit screen tests, for a fragment that opens another fragment when i click on somenthing.

In my case i found this solution.
it's a little late to answer this, i know, but this might help someone else.
I'm using kotlin and roboletric

```
fun MyFragment.checkFragmentIsOpen(
    fragClass: Class<out BaseFragment>
) {
    val fragments = activity?.supportFragmentManager?.fragments ?: listOf()
    var isOpen = false
    for (fragment in fragments) {
        if (fragment.javaClass.isAssignableFrom(fragClass)) {
            if (fragment.isVisible) {
                isOpen = true
            }
            break
        }
    }

    assertTrue(isOpen)
}
```

This is an extension function and can be called where i have MyFragment reference.
So i get all the fragments in supportFragmentManager and than check if matchs with my fragClass parameter, than i check if the fragment is visible.

```
launch { // inside here i have MyFragment reference - this: MyFragment
            clickPrimaryButton()
            checkFragmentIsOpen(MyAnotherFragment::class.java)
        }
```

This solve my problem, hope it helps